# How to catch the error while setting html string to div's innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set innerHTML of DIV with the HTML string. The HTML string may have buttons with onclick events. onclick event might have attached to some function which might not be availabe with the HTML String.

For example,

HTML String:

```
var htmlString = "<div><img onerror='someFunc()' src='path/to/image'>Click Me </img> </div>";
```

In the above html string, the **someFunc** function is NOT available with the HTML String.

Setting the innerHTML:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlString;
```

So, when i set the htmlString to innerHTML of div, it throws **Uncaught ReferenceError: someFunc is not defined**

I tried to catch the error using `try catch`  but catch block is not executed.

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaganathan/fkraqo6s/)

Please help me.

Comment: I'm almost sure you can't. What you can do is to use `addEventListener` to attach event handlers. And btw what are you going to do inside a catch block? :) http://jsfiddle.net/fkraqo6s/3/

Comment: In catch block i have to show some kind of alert message saying that, the html string you provided has some errors. Even i tried to add onerror event listener to div. but no luck :(

Comment: Why are you using inline event handlers?

Comment: @JLRishe htmlString might have inline event handlers NOT in our code

Comment: The thing you are trying to achieve cannot be done that way. try to load each image on the DOM separately and catch the error.

Comment: FYI, jsfiddle doesn't need tags such as `<html>`, `<body>` and there is seperate window for js and css.

Comment: @astro htmlString might have 100s of images. i dont want to write separate handlers for each one

Comment: It is not secure to insert html strings you can't control without sanitizing inline event handlers. Your application will be vulnerable to script injection.

Comment: As @Yury Tarabanko suggested, its better to sanitize the HTML string to avoid security issues as well as errors which are from the undefined functions bound with the DOM events.

Thanks every one. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Here i have demonstrated without using a try catch. Working on chrome. Im not sure how it will work on other browsers.

```
var images = ['/asd','anotherurl'];

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
    console.log(images[i]);
    var img = new Image();

    img.src = images[i];
    if(img.height > 0){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(img);
        document.getElementById('div').appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q8mo2df8/

Comment: JsFiddle link is broken [navigating to older version of jsfiddle]

Comment: Please check my question. I wanted to catch errors thrown when i set the html string to dom. Your answer is something like to load the images..

Comment: There is no way to check if a file exists and accessible without loading (reading) it.

Comment: I dont want to check for file existence, but i want to load the html string content into a DOM's innerHTML and want to catch errors if there